# Mongoose: Find a record based on an object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

can you help me with this issue please?

Basically, I have three models :

- User
- Group
- Document

**Schemas:**

> User Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
//another fields..
});
```

> Group Schema

```
const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  }, // The creator user
  viewer: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }], // The viewer user
//another fields..
});
```

> Document Schema

```
const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
//another fields..
  group: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Group",
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

The problem is, I have the user who will create a document and associate it with a group, in addition to creating a group and associating another user as a viewer, as shown in the route below:

```
router.get("/shared-documents", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const group = await Group.find({
      viewer: req.session.userId
    })
    console.log(group) //successfully returns the group in json format

    let documents = await Document.find({
      group: group.id,
    });
    console.log(documents) //returns null

    return res.render("documents/index", { documents });
  } catch (error) {
    //...code continuation
  }
});
```

**Outputs:**

> console.log(group)

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62a8de9dc25365352b19476f"),
    name: 'groupOne',
    user: new ObjectId("628ec25b42a33e4635cf49b1"),
    viewer: [ new ObjectId("62aa83e67742ab3eab1b4ec3") ],
    createdAt: 2022-06-14T19:16:45.077Z,
    __v: 1
  }
]
```

> console.log(documents)

```
[]
```

I am not able to rescue the group's id field based on the viewer's id, which can be?

Comment: Would you show the output of `console.log(group)`?

Comment: I think you may need  `group._id`, not `group.id`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Of course, I updated the question

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I tried, but it still doesn't show

Comment: How about `group.pop()._id`, instead of `group.id`?

Comment: The only caveat is that if the `group` `Array` contains more than one document, [`pop()` only gives you the last element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).  This may or may not be OK for you.